# one of the classes isn't compiling, would like some guidance as to how i can get it to work

Tags: java

got some of the spec of the assignment below, some of it has not been fulfilled, any idea how i would do the bit "On completion a message should be written to the Terminal Window stating that the program completed successfully, giving the number of accounts read and the total balance"

thank you in advance

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

 public class TotalOccountBalances
 {
     // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private int count;
private inFile file;    
private Scanner input;

/**
 * Method
 */
public void closeLink()
{      
    input.close();
}

/**
 * Method
 */
public void processFiles()
{
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        string line=input.nextLine();

    }
    Count++;
}
```

}

Comment: Your title says "class isn't compiling", what error are you getting?

Comment: cannot find symbol - class inFile, it is supposed to be in the class, im just not too sure what i use it for

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what your class is intending to do:

`private inFile file;`

should be

```
private File inFile; 

private outFile File;
```

should be

```
private File outFile;
```

and then use inFile and outFile variables through the rest of the code. You have to remember that for variables, the first thing after the access modifier (private, public etc.) should be the data type - a class or primitive - and neither inFile nor outFile is a datatype.

Comment: what about outfile?
the spec i am working off says i should have both infile and outfile in the class

Comment: switch it to `File outfile`

Answer (score 1):

You've got your variable names the wrong way around

```
private outFile File;
```

should be

```
private File outFile;
```

The same applys to `inFile file`;

Also Java is *case sensitive*.

```
Count++;
```

should be

```
count++;
```

This last point accounts for a good deal of other compilation errors. [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) show that variable names start with a *lowercase* letter, so

```
private int Total;
```

would be

```
private int total;
```

Comment: anything else that's glaringly awful?

Comment: That constructor `TotalAccountBalances` doesnt match with your class name `TotalOccountBalances`. They should have the same name

Comment: how do i:
"The object created should read the first file and write to the second. On completion a message should be written to the Terminal Window stating that the program completed successfully, giving the number of accounts read and the total balance"

Comment: That is a completely different matter. Would suggest creating a new post describing what you have attempted and what's not working :)